# Can't access Radio button values in PHP?

Tags: php, forms, radio-button

This seems really simple but for whatever reason I can't access a few radio button values in PHP. I have four radio buttons but the PHP is not grabbing the values. My HTML looks like this:

```
<form id="form69" name="form69" class="wufoo topLabel page" method="post" action="test.php">
    <ul>
        <li>
            <span class="applied-before"> <label>Have you ever applied for a visa to the United States?</label>     
                    <label for="has-applied-visa">Yes</label>
                    <input type="radio" value="yes" name="appliedfvisa" id="has-applied-visa" />
                    <label for="not-applied-visa">No</label>
                    <input type="radio" value="no" name="appliedfvisa" id="not-applied-visa"  checked   />
                </span>
        </li>
    </ul>
</form>
```

When I try and grab the value in PHP it says the value is undefined.

```
<?php
if (isset($_POST['saveForm'])) {

    $appliedvisa = $POST['appliedfvisa'];

    echo '<div> TEST: ' . $appliedvisa . '</div>';

}
?>
```

When I use fidler to check what was submitted I get the correct values:

```
appliedfvisa=no&saveForm=Submit
```

But why can't my PHP access them?? I am at a complete loss.

Comment: `$POST['appliedfvisa'];` should be `$_POST['appliedfvisa'];`  - missed the `_` in front of POST

Comment: As a rule of thumb, when you start making mistakes like these, and not see them in the first 2 minutes of searching, it's time to hit the bed.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There's a typo in your code:

```
$appliedvisa = $POST['appliedfvisa'];
```

should be:

```
$appliedvisa = $_POST['appliedfvisa'];
```

I'd recommend always developing with error_reporting set to E_ALL at least, which would help you catch problems like this.

Answer (score 3):

Typo on the 4th line, you've put `$POST`, should be `$_POST`

Answer (score 1):

You are doing it wrong you should access it lik e

```
$appliedvisa = $_POST['appliedfvisa'];
```

not

```
$appliedvisa = $POST['appliedfvisa'];
```

you are missing underscore before $ sign